# Wrapping GridView text without a visible space

Tags: asp.net, html, gridview

I have a GridView with several fields, one of which can potentially have a crazy wide value in it like this:

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

If *that* sort of thing is in the field, I want it to wrap.

I can easily insert a character in code every 50 characters or so...but what character?  If I use **\r\n** or a **space** or the like, then sometimes the setting doesn't wrap (because a different row's 50 chars is wider), and I get something like this:

mmmmmmmmmm
mmmmm
llllllllll llllllllll llll

I don't want those spaces to show up; I just want the line to wrap there if it can, but otherwise to show nothing:

mmmmmmmmmm
mmmmm
llllllllllllllllllllllll

Also, I'd rather leave HtmlEncode *on* if possible.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

ItemStyle-Wrap="true" ItemStyle-Width="100" doesn't work for one long word with no space.

**Found the solution:**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("style", "word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word");
                }
            }
```

where Cells[1] is the column you want to wrap.

Answer (score 4):

stick these lines of CSS in a class, and stick that class in your grid items

```
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, supported since 1999 */
white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4 - 6 */ 
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */ 
white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS3 */ 
word-wrap: break-word; /* IE 5.5+ */
```

Comment: I'd go with a CSS only solution like this one +1.  Adding crap to the output is annoying and should be avoided.  Handle the UI stuff in the markup, I say.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a few things here.

One option is change the column in question to a TemplateColumn, and place a div in it, with the ability to generate scrollbars. I'd *really* suggest against this.

If you use a CRLF (\r\n) then you'd need to wrap it into **PRE** tags, and you'd want to change the font fact to a monospace font (such as Courier) so that 50 characters would ALWAYS be the same length.

If you want an HTML solution, then it's a matter of inserting a **BR** tag into the text at the appropriate place.

Now, you'd also want to ensure that you're checking the length of the string (making sure that it's greater than your magic number length), and that it doesn't contain a space (as a space will allow for wrapping), prior to inserting either the CRLF or the BR.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following template field properties in GridView

```
ItemStyle-Wrap="true" ItemStyle-Width="100"
```

You have to set the width, otherwise the text will not be wrapped.